# How do I represent data with multiple attributes?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a file of buildings like this:

Building_name, type, city, state

Sorted by state, city, type.  About 800 rows (if it matters).

Type can be one of Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4.  Not all cities have all types.
I want to print out the list as follows:

For each state:

```
For each city, list building grouped by type

For each type, list building grouped by city
```

I thought I could just iterate through the file and print summaries whenever state changes, but I can’t figure out how to build the summaries.  Not looking for actual code, just a method or algorithm. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read up on dictionaries.

Comment: Inefficient: create a class `Building` go through file creating instances of `Building` for each building in file and adding the instance to a list.  Then go through each factor like so: `for state in states: for b in buildings: if b.state == state: print(b)`.  For multi factors you could make a list of buildings in the given state then go through the list of that state to find buildings in the given city.  Again this is inefficient but should work.

Comment: Have you ever used pandas? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of your data like this:

```
data = [
    {"Building_name": "1A", "type" : "Type 1", "city": "Lahore", "state": "Punjab"},
    {"Building_name": "2A", "type" : "Type 2", "city": "Karachi", "state": "Sindh"},
    {"Building_name": "3A", "type" : "Type 2", "city": "Lahore", "state": "Punjab"},
    {"Building_name": "4A", "type" : "Type 1", "city": "Karachi", "state": "Sindh"},
    {"Building_name": "5A", "type" : "Type 1", "city": "Lahore", "state": "Punjab"}
]
```

If you want to show this data you can use Pandas and create pivot tables